# Error while clustering in R

Tags: r

I am performing Kmeans clustering in R tool on iris dataset available at UCI repository.

Here is the sample dataset:

```
SepalLength,SepalWidth,PetalLength,PetalWidth,Species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
```

I performed following three commands:

```
iris<-read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Experiment/t2.csv")
View(iris)
km<- kmeans(iris, 3)
```

I am getting the error shown below :

```
Error in kmeans(iris, 3) :
   more cluster centers than distinct data points.
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(iris, 3) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I thought it may be because of 5th column `Species` because it is non-numeric. So, I removed that column from dataset and then again repeated above mentioned commands. But, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that your first four columns were coded as factors or some such? BTW, the iris dataset is built into R. Start a fresh R session, and run `kmeans(iris[,-5],3)`, which works perfectly for me.

Comment: thanks .This command worked. I referred this link http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/kmeans-clustering . I just took this dataset for experiment. when I am running on dataset built into R commands are running fine.But, commands not  working for iris.csv that I created manually

Comment: Make sure the data you are clustering on are not `factor`s. Examine `str(yourdata)` to see this. (Unless your original problem was caused by something else.)

Comment: Hi stephan could you please tell me what factor is?

Comment: Read Chapter 4 in *An Introduction to R*, which can be accessed via the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```js
iris<-read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Experiment/t2.csv", header=FALSE)
```